# Socket connection/read timeout

Tags: sockets, d, dmd

I'd like to create socket with connection timeout or read timeout.

I'm trying like this:

```
Socket sock = new TcpSocket(new InternetAddress(domain, port));
sock.setOption(SocketOptionLevel.SOCKET,SocketOption.RCVTIMEO, dur!"seconds"(5));
(...)
```

It compiles without errors, it runs, it connects, it sends a request, it gets a response, but it's not breaking the connection after 5 seconds. It takes 10 seconds to receive the response from the server, and the response is complete, but it shouldn't be. I'm doing this with dmd v2.066.1 on Windows. Should this code work as I expected on other platforms?

Comment: Did you try to check lastSocketError or Socket.getErrorText? There might have been an error.

Comment: lastSocketError() and sock.getErrorText return the message like "operation completed successfully".

Comment: Is it possible you could post the full code so I could try it out myself. Unless it's plain socket usage then I can of course just write some quick code myself.

Comment: Okay tried some debugging myself and I got some questions to ask. Does the server by chance just do normal sleeps between sending (Perhaps between sending portions of the bytes.) and did you check the received bytes?

Comment: Here is the tests I did http://pastebin.com/ADH4mKb3